# Lucene geo-distance sorting performance

Tags: java, sorting, lucene, geospatial

I have a task to sort search results not only by relevance of string fields of indexed documents, but also by distance from a given geographical point to a point associated with each document being indexed. It should be mentioned that only top-ten or so matched documents should be included into a result set. Also it's not important to sort by precise distance, only kind of "distance levels" from the given point are important.

Technically I have successfully implemented the task. The geographical part of the task was implemented as a `CustomScoreQuery`-derived class:

```
private static class DistanceQuery extends CustomScoreQuery {

  public DistanceQuery(final Query _subQuery, final SpatialStrategy _strategy, final Point _bp) {
    super(_subQuery, new FunctionQuery(_strategy.makeDistanceValueSource(_bp)));
  }

  @Override
  protected CustomScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider(AtomicReaderContext _context) throws IOException {
    return new CustomScoreProvider(_context) {
      @Override
      public float customScore(int _doc, float _subQueryScore, float _valSrcScore) throws IOException {
        // the spatial strategies makeDistanceValueSource creates a ValueSource which score varies from almost 0 for nearby points to 2.7-2.8 for distant points
        // so I voluntarily chosen 2 as the normalization factor and increase subQueryScore for that factor at max;
        logger.debug("customScore for document {}: [subQuery={}, valScore={}", this.context.reader().document(_doc).getField(IndexedField.id.name()).numericValue().toString(), _subQueryScore, _valSrcScore);
        return (_valSrcScore > 2 || _valSrcScore < 0) ? _subQueryScore : _subQueryScore + (2 - _valSrcScore);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and wrap a given "textual" query with this geospatial "enhancement".

Generally speaking the chosen strategy gives me pretty reasonable results. As one may see, the final score just slightly exceeds the initial query score (by 2 at max). And with typical results scores of a dozen and more, this geospatial addition works just as a way to "post-sort" otherwise similar documents.

With few hundreds or thousands test documents in the index, performance of the wrapped query was also good enough. It's about 10-50 milliseconds per search and this is just 2-5 times slower than an unwrapped query.

But when I switched from a test to a real-world DB and the number of documents in the index raised from a thousand to approximately 10 millions and is going to increase even more (with an estimation of a hundred millions in a near future), then the situation have changed dramatically. Actually I can't get any search results anymore because JVM goes out of memory and processor. Currently it can't finish the search in JVM with -Xmx6g and more.
Certainly I could buy a better hardware for the task, but the problem is likely to be solved by choosing a more appropriate sorting strategy.

One solution is to completely avoid geo-sorting provided by Lucene and manually sort top N items of the result set if items relevance scores are similar. And I'm going to choose this way if nothing else helps.

But my question is whether more adequate solutions exist. Maybe I can somehow split result items by classes of equivalence (with same or similar enough scores) and apply geo-spatial sorting only to first few classes? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how elasticsearch implements this in the function_score query. You can probably reuse a few things from what they do. If I remember correctly, they can optionally use faster but less accurate distance calculation algorithms as well. You probably want to do something similar.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm going to evaluate this possibility and then will write a response, and approve your answer, hopefully in a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using another CustomScoreProvider for DistanceQuery:

```
public class DistanceQueryScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public DistanceQueryScoreProvider(LeafReaderContext context, double x, double y) {
        super(context);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScore) throws IOException {
        Document d = context.reader().document(doc);
        double geomX = d.getField(Consts.GEOM_X_FIELD).numericValue().doubleValue();
        double geomY = d.getField(Consts.GEOM_Y_FIELD).numericValue().doubleValue();
        double deglen = 110.25;
        double deltaX = geomY - y;
        double deltaY = (geomX - x) * Math.cos(y);
        return -Double.valueOf(deglen * Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY)).floatValue();
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch [implementation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7560101ec73331acb39a042bde6130e59e4bb630/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/geo/GeoDistance.java) of `plane` distance function from [Sorting by Distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html) was slower, than above code function `customScore`. This function was implemented based on article [Geographic distance can be simple and fast](http://jonisalonen.com/2014/computing-distance-between-coordinates-can-be-simple-and-fast/)

user3159253, maybe you have your answer for this thread?